The distribution of a random variable under P
SECTION 1 of Chapter 5 in Pollard says "In applications of conditioning, ...The typical calculation starts from a partition of the sample space $\mathbb{Q}$ into finitely many disjoint events, such as the sets $\{T = t\}$ where some random variable $T$ takes each of its possible values $1, 2, \dots, n$. From the probabilities $\mathbb{P}\{T = t\}$ and the conditional distributions $\mathbb{P}(\cdot | T = t)$, for each $t$, one calculates expected values as weighted averages.
$\mathbb{P}X = \Sigma_t \mathbb{P}(X\{T = t\}) = \Sigma_t \mathbb{P}\{X | T = t)\mathbb{P}\{T = t\}$.
Notice that the weights $\mathbb{Q}\{t\} := \mathbb{P}\{T = t\}$ define a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on the range space $\tau = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, the distribution of $T$ under $\mathbb{P}$. (That is $\mathbb{Q} = T\mathbb{P}$.)

What does "under $\mathbb{P}$" mean?
What does $T$ followed by $\mathbb{P}$ mean?


So, in probability theory, a (real-valued) random variable $T:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is defined as a measurable function between a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mu)$ and the space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\Omega$ is called the sample space, $\mathcal F$ is called the event space, and $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ (I let you check wikipedia for details).
Hence, given the measure $\mu$, we call the distribution of $T$ under $\mu$ the measure $\nu_{\mu,T}$, which is defined for every set $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ as
$$\nu_{\mu,T}(B):=\mu(\{\omega\in \Omega : T(\omega)\in B\}) \tag1 $$
Now, since definition $(1)$ above is applicable to any arbitrary measure $\mu $ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, it is in particular true for $\mu\equiv\mathbb P$, hence the distribution of $T$ under $\mathbb P$ simply refers to the measure
$$\nu_{\mathbb P,T}:B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\mapsto\mathbb P \big(\{\omega\in \Omega : T(\omega)\in B\}\big).$$
More generally, given $(X_1,\Sigma_1)$, $(X_2,\Sigma_2)$ two measure spaces, $\mu$ a measure on $(X_1,\Sigma_1)$, and $T:X_1\to X_2$ a measurable map between them, we denote by $T\mu$ and call the pushforward measure of $\mu$ (under $T$) the map
$$T\mu : S_2\in\Sigma_2 \mapsto \mu\big(\{x_1 \in X_1 : T(x_1)\in S_2\}\big). $$
So $T\mathbb P$ denotes the pushforward of $\mathbb P$ under $T$, and basically, the distribution of $T$ under $\mathbb P$ and the pushforward of $\mathbb T$ under $T$ are the same thing.
(Note that there are a bunch of different notations used to denote the pushforward, the one I have seen most often used is $T_\sharp\mu$, but you can see some other common ones on wikipedia)
